# Get all duplicate values from multiple list in Java

Tags: java, collections, java-5

I want to get all values that has duplicate from multiple List of Integers.
The confusing part is these list of Integers are inside a Map of Map like this LinkedHashMap<String, LinkedHashMap<String, List>> streams

```
// sample value
{
    break_desc100=
    {
        bDesc_1000=[62, 72, 82, 92, 102, 112, 122], 
        bDesc 1001=[180, 190, 200, 210, 220, 230, 240], 
        cMessage_1000=[112], 
        cMessage_1001=[232]
    }
}
// for this one I want to get 112
```

So far I tried using retainAll but my code doesn't work if the list with duplicate are not next to each other.

```
for (Map.Entry<String,LinkedHashMap<String,List<Integer>>> entry : streams.entrySet()) {
     String currentStream = entry.getKey();
     LinkedHashMap<String,List<Integer>> bDescList = entry.getValue();
     for (Map.Entry<String,List<Integer>> bDesc : bDescList.entrySet()) {
          if (firstIteration) {
              prevBDesc = bDesc;
              firstIteration = false;
          } else {
              List<Integer> currentList = prevBDesc.getValue();
              List<Integer> nextList = bDesc.getValue();
              duplicates = new ArrayList<Integer>(currentList);
              duplicates.retainAll(nextList);
              allDuplicates.addAll(duplicates); //Set<Integer>
              prevBDesc = bDesc;
          }
     }
}
```

EDIT:
Sorry guys I forgot to add that it is running on Java 1.5.

Comment: Counts an element as duplicate if it appears several times in one list or if an element appears in several lists?

Comment: if it at least show up twice on any of list, I should be able to get that number

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems like a suitable task for streams:

```
Map<Integer, Long> counts = streams.values().stream()
       .flatMap(bDescList -> bDescList.values().stream())
       .flatMap(nextList -> nextList.stream())
       .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                Function.identity(), 
                Collectors.counting()));

counts.values().removeIf(c -> c == 1L);

Set<Integer> duplicates = counts.keySet();
```

This code first creates a map of counts. For this, it first streams the values of the outer map and then uses `Stream.flatMap` to create a new stream with the values of all the inner maps. As these values are actually lists, we need to use `Stream.flatMap` again, to finally get a stream of `Integer`. (I've kept the variable names from your question).

We collect to a map of counts, where the keys are the numbers from all the inner maps' list values, and the values are the counts for each one of these numbers, accross all maps and lists.

Then, we remove all entries from the counts map that have a value of `1`. The remaining keys are the duplicate numbers.

---

**EDIT:** Here's the equivalent code in Java 5...

```
Map<Integer, Long> counts = new HashMap<Integer, Long>();

for (Map<String, List<Integer>> bDescList : streams.values()) {
    for (List<Integer> bDesc : bDescList.values()) {
        for (Integer n : bDesc) {
            Long c = counts.get(n);
            if (c == null) {
                c = 0L;
            }
            counts.put(n, c + 1);
        }
    }
}

Iterator<Long> it = counts.values().iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    Long c = it.next();
    if (c == 1L) {
        it.remove();
    }
}

Set<Integer> duplicates = counts.keySet();
```

The rationale is exactly the same here... We create a map of counts by iterating the map of maps of lists, then we remove entries with a count of 1 and the remaining keys are the duplicates.

Comment: Sorry forgot to add that it runs on Java 1.5

Answer (score 3):

#### Edit

This Assumes that you are looking for any duplicate values. This includes finding duplicates in the same list. Correct me if I misunderstood the question.

---

You could do this in O(N) time and O(N) space by traversing the nested hash while counting the occurrences of each integer. Then we can filter to integers with more than one occurrence.

```
Map<String, List<Integer>> innerMap = new HashMap<>();
innerMap.put("bDesc_1000", Arrays.asList(62, 72, 82, 92, 102, 112, 122));
innerMap.put("bDesc_1001", Arrays.asList(180, 190, 200, 210, 220, 230, 240));
innerMap.put("cMessage_1000", Collections.singletonList(112));
innerMap.put("cMessage_1001", Collections.singletonList(232));

Map<String, Map<String, List<Integer>>> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("break_desc100", innerMap);

Map<Integer, Integer> occurrenceMap = new HashMap<>();
map.forEach((outerKey, outerValue) -> {
    outerValue.forEach((innerKey, innerValue) -> {
        innerValue.forEach((element -> occurrenceMap.merge(element, 1, Integer::sum)
        ));
    });
});

List<Integer> duplicates = occurrenceMap.entrySet().stream()
        .filter(e -> e.getValue() > 1)
        .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(duplicates);
```

output

```
[112]
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add that it runs on Java 1.5